# Python Tkinter - How to make certain code use less memory

Tags: python, memory, tkinter, processing

I am programming an Othello game in a GUI. I have begun working on the animations that flip certain tiles, which is here. My computer(s) will start choking when the when the amount of tiles on the board becomes larger. I do not know what to do to simplify this code or use less memory. (I can use an automove key I have enabled to finish the game at light speed, without the animations. That works fine.) Here is the definition I am using to flip the tiles.

```
    def animateFlips(self, i):
    self._canvas.delete(tkinter.ALL)
    column_width = self._canvas.winfo_width()/Othello.COLUMNS
    row_height = (self._canvas.winfo_height()-self._scoreBoard)/Othello.ROWS
    newBoard = self._game.board
    animatedTileCoords = []
    color = ''
    oppcolor = ''
    if self._game.turn == 2:
        color = 'black'
        oppcolor = 'white'
    elif self._game.turn == 1:
        color = 'white'
        oppcolor = 'black'
    for x in range(Othello.COLUMNS):
        for y in range(Othello.ROWS):
            x1 = x * column_width
            y1 = y * row_height
            x2 = x1 + column_width
            y2 = y1 + row_height
            self._canvas.create_rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2)
            if self._game.board[x][y] == 1:
                self._canvas.create_oval(x1,y1,x2,y2,fill='black')
            elif self._game.board[x][y] == 2:
                self._canvas.create_oval(x1,y1,x2,y2,fill='white')
            elif self._game.board[x][y] == 3 or self._game.board[x][y] == 4:
                animatedTileCoords.append([x,y])
    for x, y in animatedTileCoords:
        x1 = x * column_width
        y1 = y * row_height
        x2 = x1 + column_width
        y2 = y1 + row_height
        if i == 1:
            self._canvas.create_oval(x1,y1,x2,y2,fill=oppcolor)
            self._canvas.after(50, lambda: self.animateFlips(2))
        elif i == 2:
            self._canvas.create_oval(x1 + (column_width/4),y1,x1 + (3*column_width/4),y2,fill=oppcolor)
            self._canvas.after(50, lambda: self.animateFlips(3))
        elif i == 3:
            self._canvas.create_oval(x1 + (column_width/2),y1,x1 + (column_width/2),y2,fill=oppcolor)
            self._canvas.after(50, lambda: self.animateFlips(4))
        elif i == 4:
            self._canvas.create_oval(x1 + (column_width/4),y1,x1 + (3*column_width/4),y2,fill=color)
            self._canvas.after(50, lambda: self.animateFlips(5))
        elif i == 5:
            self._canvas.create_oval(x1,y1,x2,y2,fill=color)
            newBoard[x][y] = Othello.nextTurn(self._game.turn)
    self._game = GameState(board = newBoard, turn = self._game.turn, skipped = 0)
    self.displayMoves()
    self.displayButtons()
    self.displayInfo()
    self.displayWinner(self.getWinner())
    self._canvas.bind('<Configure>',self.draw_handler)
```

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the [tag:processing] language?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to not delete and recreate the game pieces on each iteration. Draw them once, and then use the `itemconfig` method to alter the appearance of the game pieces.

Even better would be to create a `GamePiece` class so that each piece is represented by this class. Then, move the animation function inside the class. This will make your main logic *much* easier to understand.